# help with baking in blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I modeled a simple door-handle, UV'ed it, exported it to Substance where 
I  created a base-color, normal and roughness map. With these maps I wanted to bake a final base-color map in cycles, but it just won't work.

While the rendered preview output looks fine, the bake result looks completely different.

here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: curious, I have almost the same question but in 2.79

Comment: and what is  ** UV'ed it** ??? i not understand what you say with this words

Comment: *performed the UV unwrap

Comment: have a similar problem [in blender 2.79](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PVBX.png) I didn't get the color and I don't know exactly how to calibrate this to control it

Comment: the baking process appears to ignore all maps. When I disconnect all maps from the shader and bake again, the output looks exactly the same ...

Comment: These are my nodes, you can correct that the texture looked smooth, I just need to solve the color problem,maybe it helps or helps a little https://i.stack.imgur.com/pscJ6.png

Comment: humm, ok I think I found something: the door handle is just a part of a object (the whole door) and has its own material-slot. When I duplicate and part it the door-handle mesh, so that I have a new object that just consists of the door-handle, then the baking works. But why? this means extra-work

Answer (score 0):

Well, found a solution that works for me: I had to create an unconnected image-texture nodes to every material slot (for the bake result). Looks like it always wants to bake all materials and not just the selected one, and if those other materials don't have that node, then their bake-result end up in another image-texture node ...

Comment: Baking always output in the selected image texture node in each material. There is no such thing as selecting materials in Blender. Only select the image texture nodes you want to bake into across materials. If you don't want to bake in a material, do not select any image texture node.